# Why is controller missing once MVC site is deployed?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

On my local machine, I have an MVC site that works fine.  Once it is deployed into another environment, I get this error when I navigate to:

> http://envA/ControllerA/Index

```
HTTP Status Code: 404. Exception.  The controller for path 'ControllerA/Index' was not found or does not implement IController.
```

I'm not sure what is causing the difference.  Any ideas where I could start debugging this?

I'm using .NET 4.5.1 and System.Web.Mvc 5.2.2.

Comment: Do you see that `controller` as physical file in your server?

Comment: Like all controllers in a deployed environment - no.  These are CS files, which as you know get compiled during the build.

Comment: Oh alright, You get it into `dll` files.. Did you try deploying in local server, in the same way you deployed in other environment. I mean not what VS does while you run the application, but as a separate port created in local server.

Comment: Are you using Dependency Injection?  Have seen this happen with a dependency fails to be registered, due to, e.g. a mistake in configuration (differences between deployed and local envs)

Comment: This seems to be related to [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32557189/why-does-maproute-affect-parts-of-view) and may be associated with the `namespaces: new[] {"Root.MyNamespace"}` parameter in the route definition

Comment: Most of the issues I can think of have to do with the server. But there is no easy way to identify a single thing that is the cause. So, here's a few things to check to start. Is the website pointing to the correct folders with the compiled site? Is the configuration of the site (web.config) viewed through IIS Manager correct?

Comment: can you post the route config section ?

Comment: The things I would check on the live server: 1) is (the correct version of) MVC installed on the server. 2) is the correct .NET framework version installed 3) in IIS, does the site have it's own application pool in `Integrated` pipeline mode set to the correct ASP.NET version number